# How do you write Keras model summary to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

First, I'll say this is not the way to run a Keras model correctly. There should be a train and test set. The assignment was strictly to develop intuition so no test set.

I am running a model through several permutations of neurons, activation functions, batches and layers. Here is the code I am using.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X1, y1 = make_classification(n_samples=90000, n_features=17, n_informative=6, n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0, n_classes=8, n_clusters_per_class=3, weights=None, flip_y=.3, class_sep=.4, hypercube=False, shift=3, scale=2, shuffle=True, random_state=840780)

class_num = 8

# ----------------------------------------------------------------

import itertools

final_param_list = []

# param_list_gen order is  units, activation function, batch size, layers
param_list_gen = [[10, 20, 50], ["sigmoid", "relu", "LeakyReLU"], [8, 16, 32], [1, 2]]
for element in itertools.product(*param_list_gen):
    final_param_list.append(element)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, LeakyReLU
from keras.callbacks import History
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# --------  Model 1 - permutations of neurons, activation funtions batch size and layers -------- #

for param in final_param_list:
    q2model1 = Sequential()

    # hidden layer 1
    q2model1.add(Dense(param[0]))
    if param[1] != 'LeakyReLU':
        q2model1.add(Activation(param[1]))
    else:
        q2model1.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))

    if param[3] == 2:
        # hidden layer 2
        q2model1.add(Dense(param[0]))
        if param[1] != 'LeakyReLU':
            q2model1.add(Activation(param[1]))
        else:
            q2model1.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))

    # output layer
    q2model1.add(Dense(class_num, activation='softmax'))

    q2model1.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSProp', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Step 3: Fit the model

    history = q2model1.fit(X1, y1, epochs=20)
```

Seems to work fine. Now, I've been tasked to output the accuracy of each epoch and include the neurons, activation function, batches, layers

Now, this gives me all of the accuracies for each epoch

```
print(history.history['acc'])
```

This gives me the params

```
print(param)
```

This gives me a summary although I'm not sure if this is the best approach

```
print(q2model1.summary())
```

Is there a way to print out each epoch to a pandas dataframe so it looks like this?

Phase(list index + 1) | # Neurons | Activation function | Batch size | Layers | Acc epoch1 | Acc epoch2 | ......... | Acc epoch20

That's about it. If you see anything in the model itself that is blatantly wrong or if I am missing some key code please let me know

Answer (score 5):

You can try out:

```
import pandas as pd

# assuming you stored your model.fit results in a 'history' variable:
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20)

# convert the history.history dictionary to a pandas dataframe:     
hist_df = pd.DataFrame(history.history) 

# checkout result with print e.g.:    
print(hist_df)

# or the describe() method:
hist_df.describe()
```

Keras also have a CSVLogger: https://keras.io/callbacks/#csvlogger which may be of interest.